# Populate some list before returning it with RX

Tags: android, kotlin, system.reactive

I'm trying to populate a list with detailed info about an airport. First off, I'm getting the list of airports that fulfill certain condition, and getting detailed info of every item that's in the list. And finally, i'm returning the populated list.

Here'w what i have:

```
override fun createObservable(params: String): Flowable<List<AirportsEntity>> {
        val destinationAirports = mutableSetOf<AirportsEntity>()
        return this.searchFlightRepository.getDestinationsByCode(params)
            .flatMap {
                Flowable.fromIterable(it)
            }
            .flatMap {
                this.searchFlightRepository.getAirportByCode(it.destination)
            }
            .flatMap {
                destinationAirports.add(it)
                Flowable.just(destinationAirports.toList())
            }
    }
```

The above code works just fine, but it's emitting an observable per item inside the list. I wonder how to change it in order to populate the list first, and then return it when the fetching process is done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working in the end?

Comment: @lain No, it didn't work for me. It's not iterating the list. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I changed it to your solution and didn't work.

Comment: I've made a correct to my answer. If you have more issues then maybe you could provide me with the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the use of `Flowable` necessary?

Something like this would probably be more suitable:

```
    private val destinations = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4")

    fun getAirportDestinations(airportCode: String): Single<List<String>> =
            Observable.just(destinations)
                    .flatMapIterable { it }
                    .flatMapSingle { getAirportByCode(it) }
                    .toList()

    private fun getAirportByCode(destinationCode: String): Single<String> =
            Single.just("ABC1")
```

"it's emitting an observable per item inside the list" - `flatmap` will emit for every item. The use of `toList()` will mean that it "**Returns a Single that emits a single item, a list composed of all the items emitted by the finite source ObservableSource.**"

Comment: This worked like a charm. The stream was producing some errors, but I managed to fix them, and this solution was the one. Thanks!